# PHP: How can I get only the line before the last line(inputed line)?

Tags: php, txt

How can i print only the row before the last row(inputed row) and assign **$long1** and **$lat1** to the **Long** and **Lat** elements of the row before the inputed one.

The main goal is to compare the long and lat elements of the inputed row and the row before the last row(inputed row) and find the distance between them in km. I've already wrote the function, everything works perfectly unless i can't find a way to pull the row before the inputed row and assign $**long1** and $**lat1** to its elements.

I've already tried a **for loop** and the **array_push** function, but it doesn't work. I didn't find any correct answer for this one. Any help?

```
$fname = "wohnmobil.txt";

$handle = fopen($fname,"r");

if($handle != FALSE){

while(!feof($handle)) {

$zeile = fgets($handle);`
   
if (strcmp("", $zeile) != 0) {

    $arrayOfData = explode(";", $zeile);

        $long1 = $arrayOfData[1];

        $lat1 = $arrayOfData[2];

        echo"<p><b>$arrayOfData[0]</b><br>";

        echo"$long1";

        echo"$lat1";

        echo"$arrayOfData[3]";

        echo"$arrayOfData[4]";
    }
    

}
echo"<br> $long1"."$lat1</br>";
```

}

Comment: You may try to store the last read line in your while loop. If you hit the end of you file, the stored line will be the row before the last row.

Comment: @DekoSouza  Please consider adding your code as a text. Refer this [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @DB the question is how i'm going to express this line of code and store the last read line? Also the last read line is going to be the inputed row. Can you help a little bit here? I still cant find the answer and i've tried a lot of things since 5 or 6 hours.